# How to write superscript characters in gedit?

Tags: gedit

In gedit, how can I write `x^2` without using `^`? Where `2` will be the **superscript** of `x`.

Comment: While writing a simple ASCII text document?

Comment: yes, for a simple text doccument @terdon.

Comment: Use the Character Map to get the character and copy it to gedit.

Comment: how can I use the character map in gedit? @muru

Comment: can the title of the question be changed to something better. It feels like "Writing power"(something like "mental power") of x(`xorg` maybe) in gedit ?!?!

It confused me at first.

Comment: I am not good at English. Would you please suggest me a good title? @RegisteredUser

Comment: How about "How to write superscript characters in gedit?" A google search for this phrase shows this post on number 4.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Title has been edited. @RegisteredUser

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A Character Map plugin is available for gEdit.  Enable the plugin in the Preferences.  Enable the Side Pane in the View menu.  Click on the Character Map icon at the bottom of the Side Pane, then choose "Common" and you will find the superscript 4 (even though it looks like am missing superscript 1-3). Below that are the subscripts and other special characters.

To use a certain character, just drag it from the character map on the Side Pane to the document. You can then copy-paste it in the right position.

**From a question in the comments below:**
After enabling the character map plugin, you can open/view the characters by click the icon that looks like a key with an "a" on it on the bottom left corner.

In my screenshot below, there are three icons in the Side Pane:  The first is the documents icon to view all open documents, the second is the file browser for the file browser plugin and the third is the Character Map plugin.

Check screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: For some reason ,1 and 2 are found elsewhere.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Where 'elsewhere'? And how about 3?

Comment: I have enabled the `character map` plug-in. But how can I open it in Gedit?? @parto

Comment: 1,2 and 3 are in `latin-1 supplement`

Comment: At the bottom left, click the icon that looks like a key with an 'a' on it. Then at the top section, scroll till you find the common package and then look for the Superscripts therein.

Comment: @RegisteredUser I don't have a `Latin-1 supplement` section, just Latin.

Comment: I checked in character map, maybe the plugin contains different section names?

Comment: @RegisteredUser Okay. Will look for it later in the plugin.

Comment: The plugin's character map is added to the side pane, so make sure that's visible. It's organized by [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unicode)), not by [block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block) (the standalone Character Map lets you switch), so the superscript digits _are_ all in Common, though separated. ¹ ² and ³ are in the early U+00Bx range and appear near the top, with [the others further down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%B9#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block) in U+207x; you'll probably need to scroll for a bit to find them, while watching the status bar.

Comment: One thing you omitted was how to get that plugin. You need to install `gedit-plugins`; you can do this from Ubuntu Software Centre, Synaptic Package Manager, or via the CLI with `sudo apt install gedit-plugins` (prior to 14.04 use `apt-get` instead of `apt`).

Answer (score 12):

As terdon said, an ASCII Text file means ONLY text, no formatting as in Libreoffice writer files.

But in the specific case , you can use the unicode characters that refer to superscripted 0-9 and subscripted 0-9.

Here are they  ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹  ₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉

> > A document on how to tpye special characters is available offline in `Ubuntu Desktop Guide`(search for *Enter special characters*) as well as online [here on gnome.org](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.5/tips-specialchars.html.en).

Comment: Nice answer. Just a note, not just ASCII, Any flat text (by default gedit uses Unicode). Could add how to type them or mention a reference for that?. BTW, not all font provide them. I think only 2,3 was in older Unicode which are supported by most fonts

Comment: @Sneetsher I have mentioned reference.That's quite good documentation.

Comment: That's not ASCII.

Comment: @gerrit what's not ASCII?

Comment: @RegisteredUser ¹²³⁴⁵ is not [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).

Comment: @gerrit yes they are unicode, but gedit docs are ASCII text files by default(unless you use unicode)

Comment: @RegisteredUser: actually, `gedit` saves in UTF-8 by default (or maybe it depends from the `LANG` environment variable). The fact that if you don't use characters above 127 you get an ASCII document is a byproduct of how UTF-8 has been designed.

Comment: @RegisteredUser, the link is dead

Comment: @L.G. I found a new link https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/tips-specialchars.html.en. But I no longer use Ubuntu/gnome, so I am not able to verify if this works.

Answer (score 7):

`gedit` can and does support Unicode files. Use the Character Map to obtain Unicode characters. The Character Map isn't part of gedit, but is a separate application. Just click the Dash button in the corner and type 'Character Map'. Or press `Alt+F2` and type `charmap` and press enter.

Comment: there is a lot of character! How can I find out the mathematical characters??

Comment: There's a find option. Use it two search. I searched for 'two' and got to the character in a couple of tries.

Comment: @Scotia웃 I forgot to ping you.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by other answers, you can use unicode characters to do so.

The nice bit is that if you write `x^2` the characters `^2` will convert into `²` As it is done at quite low level (Xlib), it works on almost all applications.

The rule lives at `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` (other UTF-8 locales also include this file), iso8859-* locales  also have them for characters they can print

```
 <dead_circumflex> <2>              : "²"   twosuperior # SUPERSCRIPT TWO
```

Comment: I always thought this was only for some keyboard layouts.

Comment: Léo-Lam, you just need a dead_circumflex key. That is a `^` key that when pressed once does nothing, but pressing `^` and then `a`renders `â`. Of course if your default layout doesn't contain that you could "add" it with `xmodmap` ☺

Comment: I understand that; I just thought that the dead keys existed in some keyboard layouts *only*: looks like they are pretty common, since the English keyboard layout has dead keys.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a dead key with `^`, you can press it and then the number you want. It would render the number in superscript without the circumflex.

Comment: No, it's not happening in gedit!

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Simple [ASCII text documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_text_file) don't support any kind of formatting. No *italics*, no **bold**, no <sup>superscript</sup>, no <sub>subscript</sub> no nothing. If you *do* add such formatting to your file, it will no longer be a simple text document.

So, if you need that kind of functionality, use a format that supports it such as rtf or odt or (shudder) doc.

Comment: It is possible in Unicode text documents.