# Keyboard shortcut for "to the power of" (exponent) signs?

Tags: keyboard

Is there a keyboard shortcut for "to the power of" signs?

Example: ²

Comment: In which program/editor?

Comment: In any sort of text field, in general.

Comment: I think these are program specific shortcuts. For gedit for example see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/484080/how-to-write-superscript-characters-in-gedit

Comment: I looked into that and it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use specific set of  [UTF-8 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) for entering sub/super scripts. Process is simple:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
2. Type out 00b2 ( that's zero-zero-b-2)
3. Hit space or Enter key and you will have a superscript for power 2.

Like this ². Of course you will have to substitute appropriate utf character code for other subscripts